# Count amount of STARS within value range

Tags: sql-server-2008, criteria

I need to count the total amount of 'Stars' of the total per users STARS within the following values

DATABASE : MS SQL 2008 R2

```
STARAMOUNT1 = STAR score < 1.4

STARAMOUNT2 = STAR score BETWEEN 1.5 AND 2.4

STARAMOUNT3 = STAR score BETWEEN 2.5 AND 3.4

STARAMOUNT4 = STAR score BETWEEN 3.5 AND 4.4

STARAMOUNT5 = STAR score BETWEEN 4.5 AND 5.0
```

The initial SQL that gives a avarage of stars per user is:

```
    SELECT Cast(Cast(Round(AVG(Cast(b.stars AS Float)),1)
 AS Numeric(25,1)) AS VarChar(25)) AS 'Stars' 
    FROM score b
        JOIN game_users a ON a.id = b.game_users_id
        GROUP BY a.username, a.current_state
```

I then need to make a count within the above criíterias of the amount of users that has that avarage amount of stars

Can someone help me on this? :-)

Best Regards

Stig :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, though I changed part of your initial query to correspond with what you were asking:

```
;WITH UserStars AS
(
    SELECT a.username, ROUND(AVG(CAST(b.stars AS FLOAT)),1) Stars
    FROM score b
    JOIN game_users a ON a.id = b.game_users_id
    GROUP BY a.username
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN Stars < 1.4 THEN 'StarAmount1'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1.4 AND 2.4 THEN 'StarAmount2'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 2.4 AND 3.4 THEN 'StarAmount3'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 3.4 AND 4.4 THEN 'StarAmount4'
        WHEN Stars BETWEEN 4.4 AND 5.0 THEN 'StarAmount5' ELSE 'AnotherStarAmount' END StarAmount,
        COUNT(*) Users
FROM UserStars
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Stars < 1.4 THEN 'StarAmount1'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 1.4 AND 2.4 THEN 'StarAmount2'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 2.4 AND 3.4 THEN 'StarAmount3'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 3.4 AND 4.4 THEN 'StarAmount4'
         WHEN Stars BETWEEN 4.4 AND 5.0 THEN 'StarAmount5' ELSE 'AnotherStarAmount' END
```

Comment: Hi Lamak.. Wauw, I wasnt aware that a SQL query could be done that way.. I spent the entire day finding a solution for this, with several ways, but I have not come close to this in any of my research.. Working brilliant, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, there are certainly others.

```
SELECT
    u.username, u.current_state,
    STARAMOUNT1 = SUM(CASE WHEN s.score < 1.4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    STARAMOUNT2 = SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 1.5 AND 2.4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    STARAMOUNT3 = SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 2.5 AND 3.4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    STARAMOUNT4 = SUM(CASE WHEN s.score BETWEEN 3.5 AND 4.4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    STARAMOUNT5 = SUM(CASE WHEN s.score > 4.5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM dbo.score AS s
INNER JOIN dbo.game_users AS u
ON u.id = s.game_users_id
GROUP BY u.username, u.current_state;
```